# getting a different result from matrix1 * matrix2 in 2 identical methods?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, matrix-multiplication

I'm learning Matrix mathematics in unity3D.
I have this OBJ class:

```
using System;
public class Matrix
{

public float[] values { get; set; }
public int raws { get; set; }
public int colms { get; set; }

public Matrix( int r, int c, float[] v )
{
    raws = r; colms = c;
    values = new float[raws * colms];
    Array.Copy( v, values, raws * colms );
}
  
  static public Matrix operator *( Matrix a, Matrix b )
{
    if ( a.colms == b.raws )
    {
        float[] _b = new float[a.raws*b.colms];

        for ( int i = 0; i < a.raws; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < b.colms; j++ )
            {
                for ( int k = 0; k < a.colms; k++ )
                {
                    _b[i * b.colms + j] += a.values[i * a.colms + k] * b.values[k * b.colms + j];
                }
            }
        }
        Matrix V = new Matrix(a.raws,b.colms,_b);
        return V;
    }
    return null;

}
 public static Matrix Transform( Vector4 T_vc )
{
    T_vc.w = 1;
    Matrix m = new Matrix(4,4,new float[4*4]);
    float[] v={ 1, 0, 0, T_vc.x
              , 0, 1, 0, T_vc.y
              , 0, 0, 1, T_vc.z
              , 0, 0, 0,   1    };
    int i=0; foreach ( var item in v )
    {
        m.values[i] = item;
        i += 1;
    }
    return m;
}
public static Matrix TransformTo( Vector4 pos, Vector4 T_vc )
    {
    pos.w = 1f; T_vc.w = 1;
    return Transform( T_vc ) * pos;
    }

    
public static implicit operator Vector3( Matrix m )
    {
        return new Vector3( m.values[0], m.values[1], m.values[2] );
    }
public static implicit operator Vector4( Matrix m )
    {
        return new Vector4( m.values[0], m.values[1], m.values[2], m.values[3] );
    }
public static implicit operator Matrix( Vector3 vc )
    {
        return new Matrix( 4, 1, new float[4] { vc.x, vc.y, vc.z, 0 } );
    }
public static implicit operator Matrix( Vector4 vc )
    {
        return new Matrix( 4, 1, new float[4] { vc.x, vc.y, vc.z, vc.w } );
    }
}
```

And I have this on Game object:

```
public class CreatMatrex : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject g,gg;
public Vector3 v;
public Vector3 vv;
private Vector3 _v=new Vector3(9999999f,99999f,999f);
private Vector3 _vv=new Vector3(9999999f,99999f,999f);

void Update()
{
    if ( _v != v )
    {
         Matrix  x = Matrix.Transform( g.transform.position )*v;
         g.transform.position = x;
        _v = v;
    }
    if ( _vv != vv )
    {   Matrix  x =Matrix.TransformTo( gg.transform.position,vv );
        gg.transform.position = x ;
        _vv = vv;
    }
  }
}
```

When I add an value to the vector `v` it reset the `g.transform.position` to the `v` value `only`.
And When I add a value to the vector `vv`, it adds the `vv` to the `gg.transform.position`.
I have made operator's for casting between Matrix class and `Vector3` & `Vector4` classes.

So I know that `a[]*b[] != b[]*a[]`  for that I correct my code
**From :**

```
 if ( _v != v )
     {
          Matrix  x = Matrix.Transform( g.transform.position )*v;
          g.transform.position = x;
         _v = v;
     }
```

**To:**

```
if ( _v != v )
    {
        Matrix  x = Matrix.Transform( v )*g.transform.position;
        g.transform.position = x;
        _v = v;
    }
```

But what ever I add to the vector `v` the `g.transform.position` stay at the same value (`x` always stays `g.transform.position`).

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
public static implicit operator Vector3( Matrix m )
{
   return new Vector3( m.values[0], m.values[1], m.values[2] );
}
public static implicit operator Vector4( Matrix m )
{
   return new Vector4( m.values[0], m.values[1], m.values[2], m.values[3] );
}
```

but from this

```
float[] v={ 1, 0, 0, T_vc.x
          , 0, 1, 0, T_vc.y
          , 0, 0, 1, T_vc.z
          , 0, 0, 0,   1    };
```

I see that the transform you want to extract is not in `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` indices, but in `3`, `7`, `11`, `15` indices

Comment: https://ibb.co/jw6fg0L    <= in matrix multiplication of a[] b[] need the `a.Column  == b.Rows ` and the answer shuld be in form of [a.Row's , b.Column] .          the result should  be (4 Row's , 1 Column's) so [0] [1] [2] [3]  as x , y , z , w (Vector 3 or vector 4)  you can see here : https://www.mathbootcamps.com/multiplying-matrices/       i think my math is goed because ( vv ) got as it shuld and ( v )  not !  one of them multiplied in the Matrix class and the other in other class  its driving me crazy!!!!